# Add icons on images (for remove and edit image info)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue about define the positions of icons on pictures.
My current visual:

[image]

and I would like to have something like this:

[image]

and on hover I would like to have an edit icon, like this:

[image]

my current html:

```
<div class="artist-collection-photo">
                <button class="close" type="button">×</button>
                <a data-target="#photo-fields-5-0" data-toggle="modal">
                  <img width="120" height="120" alt="image.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                  </a>
                </div>
```

and css:

```
.artist-collection-photo {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

I would appreciate your help, I'm horrible with visual parts :(

PS: The edited the example images in photoshop

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/30/

set `.artist-collection-photo {position: relative;}`

then set `.close{position: absolute;}`

this will position the button inside the image, then position it using `top: 0;` and `right: 0;`

```
.artist-collection-photo {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
.close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

For the fade portion you see here: https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/31/

```
.img-thumbnail {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.img-thumbnail:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Great.. Thanks a lot! do you know how I could add the edit icon? :)

Comment: Excelent! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.bootply.com/IRZvpTK41g

Your containing div (the photo) needs to be set to position relative and the button X needs to be set to `position:absolute`. Tweak with the measurements. To get the button to change color on hover, just add the `button:hover` pseudoclass and change the color there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! ;)